# Remove standard T-SQL message from SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job

I have a stored procedure running in a SQL Server Agent job which loops through a list of table names and performs inserts/updates/deletes on each table in that loop. The message in the job history, viewed through the SSMS Job File Viewer, shows a concatenation of messages for each table processed as shown below. Is there any way to disable this?

The problem I have is this step processes about 100 tables and this output isn't valuable. Additionally, when there actually is an error it may not even display based on where that message is in relation to the previous messages in the concatenation, and the log only showing a limited amount of text.

Snippet of the message as appearing in the SQL Agent Job History viewer in SSMS:

Message

```
Executed as user: <REDACTED>\svc-engine. ...ted
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  --- Started: 2021-10-19 03:32:36.9133333, finished: 2021-10-19 03:32:51.2600000 with a duration of: 14347 milliseconds
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  -- <TABLENAME> processed successfully with 0 rows impacted
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  --- Started: 2021-10-19 03:32:51.7300000, finished: 2021-10-19 03:33:28.1566667 with a duration of: 36426 milliseconds
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  -- <TABLENAME> processed successfully with 0 rows impacted
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  --- Started: 2021-10-19 03:33:30.7233333, finished: 2021-10-19 03:35:45.6133333 with a duration of: 2 minutes and 14 seconds.
```

Comment: These are messages printed out in your code. They aren't "standard"

Comment: @MartinSmith That was the first thing I thought, but there is nothing in the SP creating this message.

Comment: Perhaps nothing in the SP is, but something the SP is doing *is* resulting in those message. Perhaps, for example there is an `INSERT` that affects a table with a `TRIGGER` that `PRINT`s a large amount of text (which, if so, i would suggest is a flaw).

Comment: @Larnu I can confirm there are no such triggers. And while I initially thought it appeared to be a user-created message, not finding anything which would generate it led me to believing it was system generated. Am I correct in understanding your position that this is absolutely not a system generated message?

Comment: So what is your procedure doing? Can you post its definition?

Comment: @Larnu It's creating an insert, update, or delete statement in dynamic SQL, loading that to a variable, and running EXEC sp_executesql.

Comment: Perhaps the dynamic SQL is building `PRINT` statements inside itself? Honestly, like @MartinSmith said, those aren't standard messages, so *something* is causing it, but we have nothing to be able to look at to see why.

Comment: @Larnu Understood. The dynamic sql is not building any print statements, and the only `RAISERROR` statements exist in `CATCH` blocks. I'm a little hesitant to provide the SQL to review, but with support that this is a user-generated message created *somewhere*, I'm going to go down that path. Thank you for your help.

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing the code. Please just post the code